# Characteristic Polynomial of a Matrix $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we had a matrix $V$ which was a complex square matrix($n$ x $n$) with characteristic polynomial $\prod_{i=1}^{m} (x - \lambda_i)^{k_i}$ with $f(x)$ is a complex polynomial.

What is the characteristic polynomial $f(V)$?

I'm not entirely sure what this question is asking. Because the way I look at it, if we have that $f(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial for $V$. Doesn't that imply that $f(V)$ is $0$ by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem and satifisies the equation: $(V - I_n\lambda_1)^{k_1} (V - I_n \lambda_2)^{k_2} \dots(V - I_n \lambda_m)^{k_m} = 0$ so wouldn't this be the characteristic polynomial $f(V)$ for the matrix $V$?

Comment: In this question, $f$ is not necessarily the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't understand what you mean by that. Why is that the case?

Comment: Because all they said is that "$f$ is a complex polynomial".  Not every complex polynomial is the characteristic polynomial of $V$.

Comment: Oh wait, I misread the question.

Comment: Perhaps you're meant to (partially) prove the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, then

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No, I believe you're right. I wrote the question wrong.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the hint though, from there I just apply the division algorithm until I reach a polynomial $f(V)$ correct?

Comment: $p(x)=x^{n}$ is the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $f(V)$ because $f(V)=0$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $V$, then $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(V)$.

You should find that the characteristic polynomial of $f(V)$ is
$$
\prod_{i=1}^m (x - f(\lambda_i))^{k_i} 
$$

Comment: I see this as $f(V)$ divides $\prod_{i=1}^{m} (x - \lambda_i)^{k_i}$ but I can't figure out how to use this hint.

Comment: If we know all the eigenvalues of $f(V)$ up to multiplicity, then we can find its characteristic polynomial.